# Error submitting Cloudbuild job from Cloudfunctions if

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-build, google-cloud-kms

Hopefully this is a simple one for someone with a little deeper knowledge than me...

I have a Cloudfunction that responds to webhook calls to submit jobs to Cloudbuild using the API.  This works fine except that now we have some jobs that need to use KMS keys from a different project.

```
secrets:
- kmsKeyName: projects/xxx/locations/global/keyRings/xxx/cryptoKeys/xxx
```

With this included in cloudbuild.yaml the api call to submit the Cloudbuild job returns:

```
400 invalid build: failed to check access to "projects/xxx/locations/global/keyRings/xxx/cryptoKeys/xxx"
```

I've tried adding both the Cloudfunction and Cloudbuild service accounts from the calling account to the account that hosts KMS to everything I could think of, including Owner.

[This](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/securing-builds/set-service-account-permissions) article has simple and clear instructions for accessing Container Registry and other services in another account, but nothing about KMS.  This error doesn't seem to trigger any meaningful results in searches, and it doesn't look familiar to me at all.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Cloud KMS API was not enabled on the project running Cloudbuild.  It's unfortunate that the error message was so vague.  In fact, I diagnosed the issue by running `gcloud kms decrypt ...` in a Cloudbuild job which helpfully told me that the API needed to be enabled.